# Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore does not have a constructor that takes the parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity, unity-container

I being a newbie working on app with MVC5 and EF 6. I am using dependency injection to resolve my classes. Everything was ok untill I changed the connection string and changed something(i dont know) in my dependency registering class that is unity config.

Now whenever i run it, it gives me this error. Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore does not have a constructor that takes the parameters. I am using Unity nuget package manager

below is my code, any help would be appreciated

```
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
    using Oxford.Core.Data;
    using Oxford.Data;
    using Oxford.Services;
    using OxfordLibrary.Models;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using Unity;
    using Unity.Injection;

    namespace OxfordLibrary.App_Start
    {
        public class UnityConfig
        {
            public static void RegisterComponents()
            {
                // Repository
                var container = new UnityContainer();

                // register all your components with the container here
                // it is NOT necessary to register your controllers

                // e.g. container.RegisterType<ITestService, TestService>();
                container.RegisterType(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(EfRepository<>));

                container.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>();


                // Services

                container.RegisterType<IMasterService, MasterService>();

                // Resolve

                container.RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, UserStore<ApplicationUser>>(
                       new InjectionConstructor(typeof(ApplicationDbContext)));
            }
        }
    }
```

OxfordLibrary is name of my project
Exception I am getting is : 
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=The type Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`1[[OxfordLibrary.Models.ApplicationUser, OxfordLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] does not have a constructor that takes the parameters (ApplicationDbContext).
  Source=Unity.Abstractions
  StackTrace:
   at Unity.Injection.InjectionConstructor.ConstructorByType(Type typeToCreate, Type[] types)
   at Unity.Injection.InjectionConstructor.AddPolicies(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, String name, IPolicyList policies)
   at Unity.UnityContainer.RegisterType(Type typeFrom, Type typeTo, String name, LifetimeManager lifetimeManager, InjectionMember[] injectionMembers)
   at Unity.UnityContainerExtensions.RegisterType[TFrom,TTo](IUnityContainer container, InjectionMember[] injectionMembers)
   at OxfordLibrary.App_Start.UnityConfig.RegisterComponents() in D:\Programs\2018\OxfordLibrary\OxfordLibrary\App_Start\UnityConfig.cs:line 35
   at OxfordLibrary.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in D:\Programs\2018\OxfordLibrary\OxfordLibrary\Global.asax.cs:line 20

Comment: Please add the full exception message and stack trace of the exception and all its inner exceptions.

Comment: @Steven I have updated that